# Ajax / Json result is returned but does not display

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have the following JQuery AJAX call. When the the output variable is alerted everything looks fine, but I cannot display individual elements successfully. Can anyone see why?

**JQUERY**

```
$('#test_load').click (function () {
    //ajax callbacks
    $.get('js/request.php?p=template&t=<?php  echo $_SESSION['user']['ajax_token']; ?>&a=content|content', function (output){
        //alert (output);
        if (output.error) {$('#test_content').html(output.error);} else {$('#test_content').html(output.result);} 
    });
return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="one_col">

<div id="test_content">
<?php //print_r($output['r']); ?>
</div>
<a href="#" id="test_load">Test pattern</a>

</div>
```

Comment: What is `output`? `console.log` it. make sure it's a json-"object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you haven't specified the type of data that you want to receive, try this:

```
$('#test_load').click (function () {
    $.get('js/request.php?p=template&t=<?php  echo $_SESSION['user']['ajax_token']; ?>&a=content|content', function (output){
        if (output.error) {$('#test_content').html(output.error);} else {$('#test_content').html(output.result);} 
    }, "json");
return false;
});
```

notice the `"json"` parameter at the end of the function

Comment: Cheers. I'm new to Json & I missed that detail while improving my previous AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataType` as `json` 
Refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
 $('#test_load').click (function () {
    //ajax callbacks
    $.get('js/request.php?p=template&t=<?php  echo $_SESSION['user']['ajax_token']; ?>&a=content|content', function (output){
        //alert (output);
        if (output.error) {$('#test_content').html(output.error);} else {$('#test_content').html(output.result);} 
    },'json');
return false;
});
```